# How to get programatically all capablities that enable in manifest for UWP app

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

I want to create a library, and I need to programmatically check to what capabilities enable in UWP app that use my library.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the appxmanifest directly as a XML file is the way to go here. Something like this:

```cs
var doc = XDocument.Load("AppxManifest.xml", LoadOptions.None);
var xname = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10");
var capabilitiesNode = doc.Root.Descendants(xname + "Capabilities").First();

foreach (var capability in capabilitiesNode.Descendants())
{
    Debug.WriteLine(capability.Name + ": " + capability.Attribute("Name").Value);
}
```

Comment: No, there aren't any. I guess you can check some specific permission by trying to invoke an api call which requires it, for example call Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync() to check geo permission. But no way to get full list without reading app manifest.

Comment: I think [Xamarin PermissionsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin) is good library for cross platform development, but this is not complete yet.