# Programmatically read capabilities from manifest of UWP app at runtime

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, system.reflection

My question is similar to [How to get programatically all capablities that enable in manifest for UWP app
 (sic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043022/how-to-get-programatically-all-capablities-that-enable-in-manifest-for-uwp-app), but I wish to do this at **runtime** instead of reading directly from the Package.appmanifest or AppManifest.xml file.

I am writing an SDK for UWP, and want to be able to figure out which capabilities have been enabled for the parent app.

Currently, I am using code like the following to *try* to get the manifest, but I can't figure out how to get the AppManifest xml or query for values from the manifest:

```
// Need this for extension method GetTypeInfo()
using System.Reflection;

// Am I getting correct manifest here?
var manifest = typeof(classInMySdk).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.ManifestModule;

// Now how do I query for "Capabilities" in the manifest?
```

Alternatively, if there is some other API that let's you query for "Capabilities", I'd like to know about that.

Comment: The question you link to is also a runtime check. This is a duplicate question.

Comment: The XML manifest is there at runtime. Nothing is embedded in the assembly.